# Parent VC delegate methods not called when embedded containerVC methods are called

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have a Parent VC with a Child VC embedded in a container. Both VCs conform to delegate, but only the child delegate methods are called. How can I get both VC's delegate methods to respond? Am I missing something with delegate pattern for container views? Thanks in advance for any help.

Central class:

```
public protocol BLEManagerDelegate: class {
   func bLEManagerShowAlert(message: String)
}

public class BLEManager: NSObject {

  static let sharedInstance = BLEManager()
  weak var delegate: BLEManagerDelegate?

   public func postMessage() {
      delegate?.bLEManagerShowAlert(message: message)
   }
}
```

ParentVC

```
class HomeVC: ContentViewController, BLEManagerDelegate {

    var bLEManager = BLEManager.sharedInstance 

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        bLEManager.delegate = self
    }

    // delegate methods

    func bLEManagerShowAlert(message: String) {
    // THIS METHOD IS NOT GETTING CALLED
    }
}
```

Container view embedded into ParentVC

```
class ChildVC: UITableViewController, BLEManagerDelegate {

    var bLEManager = BLEManager.sharedInstance 

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        bLEManager.delegate = self

    // delegate methods

    func bLEManagerShowAlert(message: String) {
    // This method IS getting called
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `delegate` property can only hold a reference to one object at a time. As soon as your `ChildVC` sets itself as the delegate, the `parentVC` is no longer the delegate.

If you want to notify multiple objects you could look at using `NotificationCenter`

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need Singleton BLEManager? Where do you call postMessage()? If alerts are displayed in their own view controllers just write default implementation for a default alert message via protocol extension. Then just implement the methods in VCs for custom messages. If you want multiple delegates you should try this: http://www.gregread.com/2016/02/23/multicast-delegates-in-swift/